# Android - GridView scroll is reloading images in universal image loader

Tags: android, gridview, universal-image-loader

I'm using universal image loader, but the images are reloaded every time I scroll up and down.

I'm using below code.

Configuration - >

```
  ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .memoryCache(new WeakMemoryCache())
                .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
                .discCacheFileNameGenerator(new Md5FileNameGenerator())
                .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.LIFO)
//          .enableLogging() // Not necessary in common
                .build();
        // Initialize ImageLoader with configuration.
        ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
```

Options->

```
options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .resetViewBeforeLoading()
                .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
                .cacheInMemory(true)
                .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
                .build();
```

view ->

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View workingview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_item_photo_icon, null);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) workingview.findViewById(R.id.picture);
            ImageAware imageAware = new ImageViewAware(imageView, false);
            imageLoader.displayImage("file://" + imageUrls.get(position), imageAware, options, new SimpleImageLoadingListener());
            return workingview;
        }
```

Please let me know where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit of chache in android around 1MB of image cashing it clears cache and download again that is why it reloads again images.
Its is proper way if you are not downloading images in your SD card of phone memory.
You can not hold much data in caching.